# What is the purpose of the `vm_list` in KVM?

Tags: kvm

I started investigating how virtual machines are scheduled in [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page), and stumbled upon the [vm_list](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kvm_host.h#L146), but I got stuck. So what is the purpose of the `vm_list`? Any relation to scheduling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the basic cloud architecture which had VMs on the top of Hypervisor;

KVM ideally allocates and tracks resource of all the VMs .

The two structs mm_struct and vm_list are a part of kvm struct to maintain resource allocation to n number of VMs spawn by KVM

Hope it helped.

Cheers!!